# AngularJS Routing Function is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

My Angular Routing Function is not working - There is a page load, but without the 'home.html' file. This is my code:

Index.html

```
<html  ng-app="App" class="no-js" lang="en" >
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>    
  </head>

  <body ng-cloak> 
  <div ng-controller="main">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('App', ['ngRoute']) 
    .controller('$routeProvider', router)
    .controller('main', main);

function router($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: '_pages/home.html',
            controller: 'main'
          });

};
function main ($scope) {
console.log("done");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the directory structure is correct? EDIT: is this node file in the same directory as the _pages folder?

Comment: Directory should be fine - home.html is in a subfolder (file above: index.html is one folder level up)

Comment: the router stuff should be in `.config` call, you have it in a controller

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: when I change controller to config, then there is a '[$injector:modulerr]' error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular $providers working just in config state.
Eg:

```
angular
.module('App', ['ngRoute']) 
.config(['$routeProvider', router]);
function router($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: '_pages/home.html',
        controller: 'main'
      });

};
```

Answer (score 3):

The route configuration is done in config and not controller. Change your code as below:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

   angular
    .module('App', ['ngRoute']) 
    .config(router)
    .controller('main', main);

  function router($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: '_pages/home.html',
        controller: 'main'
      });

  };

  function main ($scope) {
    console.log("done");
  }
});
```

Comment: Oops. We answered in same time. Your solution is great. :)